# How to find the resolution size in format "240x320" from string?

Tags: php, regex

I have a sample code:

```
$text = "240 x 400 pixels, 3.0 inches (~155 ppi pixel density)";
```

And using regex:

```
preg_match_all('/(.*)( x )(.*)/i', $text, $arr);

print_r($arr[0]);
```

Result not change, how to fix it ?

Comment: `.*` matches any character sequence, so it is no wonder that your expression  matches the whole string.

Comment: @FelixKling: I think changing it to `.*?` might fix things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to change your regular expression to something like this:

```
preg_match_all('/(\d+) x (\d+)/i', $text, $arr);
```

The "." matches any character, so when you used `.*` it just matched the whole string---it doesn't matter what you put after it. With regular expressions, it's generally a good rule of thumb to be as specific as possible. In this case `\d+` will match 1 or more numeric digits, so it will stop matching when it gets to the first non-numeric digit, in this case, a space.

Here's the result of `$arr` that I get with your `$text` string and the updated regular expression:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 240 x 400
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 240
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 400
        )

)
```

Hopefully it's closer to what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You may want this instead: `/(\d+)\s*x\s*(\d+)/i`

It will match a number `\d+`, followed by arbitrary amount of spaces `\s+`, then `x`, then arbitrary amount of spaces, then another number `\d+`. It also captures the numbers in the index 1 and index 2 of the match array.

Answer (score 1):

```
/(\d+)(?:\sx\s)(\d+)/i
```

Use `.` carefully.

Answer (score 1):

This method will give you a key to access the width / height of these values. By using \d you're targeting digits only

```
$text = "240 x 400 pixels, 3.0 inches (~155 ppi pixel density)";
preg_match_all('/(?P<width>\d+) x (?P<height>\d+)/i', $text, $arr);
print_r($arr);exit;
```